# Extract ngrams that are common for several sentences

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I'm trying to extract ngrams that are common for several sentences.

**What I have:**
My data consists of separate sentences:

```
data = [
    'Design and architecture project',
    'Web inquiry for products',
    'Software for non-profit project',
    'Web inquiry for vendors'
]
```

**What I do:**

```
from nltk import everygrams
from collections import Counter

full_corpus = ' '.join(data)
ngram_counts = Counter(everygrams(full_corpus.split(), 2, 5))
repeated_ngrams = [(' '.join(ngram), count) for ngram, count in list(ngram_counts.items()) if count > 1]
print(repeated_ngrams)
```

**What I get:**
`[('project Web', 2), ('project Web inquiry', 2), ('project Web inquiry for', 2), ('Web inquiry', 2), ('Web inquiry for', 2), ('inquiry for', 2)]`

**Problem with what I get now:**
With this approach some of ngrams consist of words from different sentences. Entries `('project Web', 2), ('project Web inquiry', 2), ('project Web inquiry for', 2)` are considered incorrect.

**What I want to get:**
`[('Web inquiry', 2), ('Web inquiry for', 2), ('inquiry for', 2)]`

Can anybody please help me with this? It seems like a common task, but I was unable to find any information about a proper solution.

*Goal behind the task:*
I'm going to use extracted ngrams to suggest autocomplete for users. It would be wise to suggest word `'for'` when user types in `'inquiry'`, for example.
However, if, based upon currently extracted ngrams, word `'web'` will be suggested after user types the word `'project'`, that will be wrong.

---

**Update**: I guess I have a solution, but I'm not sure if it is *optimal*:

```
end_token = "<end>"
marked_data = [f"{entry} {end_token}" for entry in data]

full_corpus = " ".join(marked_data)
ngram_counts = Counter(everygrams(full_corpus.split(), 2, 5))
repeated_ngrams = [
    (" ".join(ngram), count)
    for ngram, count in list(ngram_counts.items())
    if count > 1 and end_token not in ngram
]
print(repeated_ngrams)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to run `everygrams` for each sentence separately:

```
...
import itertools
...

ngram_counts = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
  [everygrams(el.split(), 2, 5) for el in data]))
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting approach, never thought it would work, but it does.